# PHP/MySQL resource usage

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best method to accurately determine the speed, memory usage and possibly processing power used by a PHP/MySQL page/file?

I need to measure the speed in which a PHP/MySQL script can process between thirty to 50 POSTed variables, which are then used in a prepared statement which does a SELECT query on a MySQL database table with at least two INNER JOINS.

Comment: Define "resources"? Do you mean memory? File handles? Disk space? Do you mean on an individual basis or operationally over the course of millions of requests? Normally this is done at the server level using monitoring tools like [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/php) or something of that sort.

Comment: I've added more specificity to my question. Is that more helpful @tadman

Comment: For trivial tests you can use tools like [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) to get a rough idea of what load your server can handle. For more sophisticated cases you'll want to explore what benchmarking suites you can make use of. Remember to make use of `EXPLAIN` on any queries you're running to be sure you're properly indexing your data.

Comment: Apache Bench, I'll have a look. Thank you.

Our indexing is very good so I'm not worried about that. I'm just wanting to make a certain query as efficient as humanly possible.

Thank you @tadman

Comment: "30-50 variables" doesn't mean much. Are these simple integer values put into columns, or are they huge JSON or payloads that need to be parsed and/or heavily processed before being inserted into many different tables? The best way to evaluate any potential code is to really lay into it with a benchmarking tool to see when your performance falls off a cliff. For most trivial appliactions the cliff is really far out there, like thousands of requests per second.

Comment: You're right - I should be more specific.

The page, depending on the logged in user's permissions, will have that amount of check boxes which are posted to a processing file and each check box will have a value of either 1 or 0 and the name attribute will determine the rest.

Comment: Doesn't sound too bad, but the proof will be when you hit up your server really hard to see how it performs. I've found tools like Node.js and [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to be really good at firing off huge numbers of requests with very specific parameters or payloads. There's also tools like [Seige](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege).

Comment: Thank you for saying that. It's not even remotely bad. However I need to prove that this certain function is barely a butterfly's sneeze when executed.

Thank you @tadman for the suggestions. How do I up vote you in the comments section?

Answer (score 0):

To benchmark effectively you'll need both traffic generators:

- [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)
- [Seige](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege)

Plus server monitoring tools like:

- [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/php)
- [Stackify](https://stackify.com/retrace-apm-php/)

Together you can expose your server to very high loads and observe where you have scaling problems.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Apparently I am still unable to up vote because I don't have enough points. Whatever that means.

@tadman's thoughts and suggestions pointed me in the right direction to help me get what I needed.

Best I can do.

Comment: Don't worry about the points, they'll come in time. Sounds like you've got quite an adventure ahead, so good luck!

Comment: I just wanted to express my gratitude, that's all :)

Thanks again man.